# Effect of reliability on t-test

Tags: t-test, reliability

I have some problem with investigating the effect of reliability on the t-test. 
Basically it is assumed that lower reliability leads to a broader confidence interval or higher SD, which has a reasonable effect on power of investigation. 
However could the SD  not also be lower in the case of low reliability and therefore increase the probability of the alpha error?

As an example the results of a pilot study:

TRUE values: Mean 51, SD 18
Rater 1: Mean 49, SD 20
Rater 2: Mean 53, SD 16

Obviously for Rater 2 the SD is lower than the TRUE SD (measured with a more reliable method), suggesting a higher accuracy. However, the reliability in a test retest situation is the same as in Rater 1.

Now if I want to investigate the required sample sizes for a targeted effect size (using this pilot study) the sample sizes needed would be even lower than for the more reliable method, as it does not account for the higher mean of Rater 2 compared to TRUE mean.

Do you have any suggestion how to discuss that problem?